# Convert dataset value to a list with group by a particular row value

Tags: c#

I have the following dataset

```
|Application|Menu|    
|App1|Menu1|    
|App1|Menu2|    
|App1|Menu3|    
|App2|Menu1|    
|App2|Menu2|    
|App2|Menu3|    
|App3|Menu1|    
|App3|Menu2|    
|App3|Menu3|
```

I need to convert it to the following class structure group by application name:

```
public class ApplicationList
{
    public List<Application> Applications {get; set;}
}

public class Application
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
}
```

Need like this

```
App1
    Menu1
    Menu2
    Menu3
App2
    Menu1
    Menu2
    Menu3
App3
    Menu1
    Menu2
    Menu3
```

Any help could be appreciated, I tried and gets lots of trouble on this as I don't have much experience with entity framework,

```
from DataRow dr in ds_AppDataset.Tables[0].Rows
    select new Application()
            {
                Name = dr["Application"].ToString(),
                //Menus = dr["Menu"]
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: There is no Entity Framework in what you have shown, you might consider removing that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) to group your rows by Application. Each element in the group represents a Menu

```
var apps = ds_AppDataset.Tables[0].Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(
       // key/grouping selector
       dr => dr["Application"].ToString(),
       // element selector
       dr => new Menu { MenuName = dr["Menu"].ToString() },
       // result selector
       (a, menus) => new Application {
           ApplicationName = a, 
           Menus = menus.ToList() 
       })
    .ToList();

var appList = new ApplicationList {
    Applications = apps
};
```

Or with query syntax:

```
var apps = (
   from DataRow dr in ds_AppDataset.Tables[0].Rows
   group new Menu {
     MenuName = dr["Menu"].ToString()
   } by dr["Application"].ToString() into grp
   select new Application {
     ApplicationName = grp.Key,
     Menus = grp.ToList()
   } 
).ToList();

var appList = new ApplicationList {
    Applications = apps
};
```

Comment: Do note that despite your comment, nothing in your question (or this answer) is using Entity Framework. This is simply using a `DataSet`/ `DataTable` I assume filled from an external source (such as a `SqlDataAdapter`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ef in your code but you can use following to map your dataset :

```
 var result=(from DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                select new 
                {
                    ApplicationName = dr["Application"].ToString(),
                    Menu= dr["Menu"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
           var apps = result.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationName).Select(x=>new Application()
           {
               ApplicationName = x.Key,
               Menus =x.Select(y=>new Menu(){MenuName =y.Menu}).ToList()
           });
```